# Regex for glossary replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'am writing glossary module - it must find known words in text and replace it by link.  It must not replace word if it is a link ancor (`<a href="...">word</a>`) or attribute (`<span class="word">...</span>`).

I have wrote code:

```
$x = '<div>DVB-S2. DVB-S. DVB-S2DVB-S <sss DVB-S2 /> DVB-S2 <a href="dd">DVB-S2</a> DVB-S2 Hot bird 6/Hot Bird 8/Hot bird 9, 13.0</div>';

$word = 'Hot Bird 8';
$x = preg_replace("'(?<=[\s\>])(" . $word . ")(?=[^\d\w\-])(?!([^<]+)?>)'is", "<a href=\"s2\">$1</a>", $x);

$word = 'DVB-S2';
$x = preg_replace("'(?<=[\s\>])(" . $word . ")(?=[^\d\w\-])(?!([^<]+)?>)'is", "<a href=\"s2\">$1</a>", $x);

echo $x;
```

But it replace `<a href="dd">DVB-S2</a>` to `<a href="dd"><a href="s2">DVB-S2</a></a>`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: ive tested your code and ive noticed that the first preg_replace does not do anything

Comment: More important is second regex, and problems with anchor replacement.

Comment: do you want to replace the original a tag if it does exist?

Comment: so the expression must find and replace all instances of DVB-S2 except the ones already inside <a> tag?

Comment: Yes. Except inside <a> tag or tag attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i got,i hope it works

```
   echo preg_replace("@((?!<a\s*[^<>]*>.*?))($word)((?!</a>.))@i",'$1<a href="">$2</a>$3',$html) . chr(10);
```

which will output

```
<div><a href="">DVB-S2</a>. DVB-S. <a href="">DVB-S2</a>DVB-S <sss <a href="">DVB-S2</a> /> <a href="">DVB-S2</a> <a href="dd">DVB-S2</a> <a href="">DVB-S2</a> Hot bird 6/Hot Bird 8/Hot bird 9, 13.0</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it works. I edited it to fix:

`<sss <a href="">DVB-S2</a> />`

To:

`@((?!<a\s*[^<>]*>.*?))($word)((?=[^<>\s])(?!</a>.))@i`

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this down into three rules:

1. Word is delimited on both sides by a non-word character or the BO[SL]/EO[SL].
2. Word is not between a < and its matching >.
3. Word is not between  and .

We need a positive lookahead and lookbehind for rule (1):

```
(?<=^|\W)word(?=\W|$)
```

The `\W` captures non-word characters, so anything other than letters, digits, and underscores. This isn't exactly the same as your version but you can adjust as needed. `\b` may also be a good choice, in which case you wouldn't need the caret and dollar sign.

Now, add a negative lookbehind for rule (2):

```
(?<!<[^>]*)(?<=^|\W)(DVB-S2)(?=\W|$)
```

This prevents a match when the word is preceded by a `<` and any non-`>` characters, i.e., when it is in the middle of any HTML tag.

Now, add a negative lookahead for rule (3):

```
(?<!<[^>]*)(?<=^|\W)(DVB-S2)(?=\W|$)(?!</a>)
```

This prevents a match when the word is *immediately* followed by a `</a>`. This isn't a perfect solution since the word may not be the only part of the linked text, but it might be close enough for your situation, and it passes your test case. There's probably a way to be more precise than this within a single expression, but nothing is coming to mind at the moment.

All of the above is written in .NET-dialect regex, I'm assuming PHP is similar enough for this to work for you.

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 10

Comment: Thank you anyway - your answer is very usefull for understanding technique.